# What versions of Ubuntu have shipped Unity?

Tags: unity

I was just wondering if there is another version of ubuntu, (besides 11.10) that uses unity, because I do not like to use betas and I absolutely love the unity GUI. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu started using [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) on desktop since 11.04 release. In 10.10 Unity was the default UI for the "[netbook edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_netbook)".

**Links**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29
2. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+publishinghistory
3. http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/383